# UISplitViewController with Storyboard 2 levels TableView

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UISplitViewController created with the XCode Template and using StoryBoard. It works fine showing in detail the row selected data in te masterView.

I want to add another tableview in the masterView, to have 2 levels of masterView. In the first tableview show item 0, Item 1, Item 2. Then when tap in one of these push another tableview in the same MasterView with other row values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In MasterViewController.m, add the following code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NewMasterViewController *masterViewController = [[NewMasterViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:masterViewController animated:YES];
}
```